# Partial data missing in mysql new slave

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have setup a MySQL replication cluster which has a Primary node (master), and a Secondary node (slave). I created a table(Org.Employee) and inserted 100 records in to the master node. The slave received the table and data of 100 records through replication. I took a snapshot of the data into snapshot.sql file using mysqldump. All is well till this point.

Now the Master server is down, Hence I switched over the existing slave to new master. Then I inserted 100 more records in to the new master's Org.Employee table.

Now I added a new slave and applied snapshot.sql. Org.Employee table with first 100 records are present in the new slave. Then I started slave after changing to the new master. Out of next 100 records only 80 records replicating into the new slave.

The ISSUE is slave has 180 records where as master has 200 records. 20 records are missing. However later on when I inserted however many records into master node all records are getting synced properly into the slave. But the 20 records that were missing doesn’t replicate into the new slave.

Did anyone face such issue? Any fix to resolve such issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that new master (old slave) gtid transaction ids popped into the recovered slave. These gtids popped up through mysqldump file that we took initially. That is why some gtids (records) are missing on the recovered slave. Fix: When I use reset master on the recovered slave before change to new master for replication, there are no missing records.